# background from old laptop on new laptop?

Tags: laptop, desktop, desktop-customization

My laptop was broken, so I bought a new one.

After a restart (on the new one) the background picture from old laptop is just showing on the new laptop.

Can someone explain to me how?

I do not use that image in some account, that picture was not online in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have synced both your laptops with the same Microsoft account. It stores user's preference including wallpaper, volume level etc.

Happened to me too.

Comment: tnx ! I guess that's it !

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer had helped you please mark it as accepted & close the thread.